# How do I search by list property size?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a entity in a Google App Engine Django app with a list property:

```
class Foo(db.model):
  # a list of keys for bars.
  bars = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

I want to query for Foo instances that have exactly 1 bar in their `bars` list. How could I construct that query? I am trying to find some version of

```
db.Query(Foo).filter( ... ? ...)
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it, because this particular piece of data is not indexed anywhere. You have to create a different property (`size` or something), and make it indexed. Then you can search using this property.